# Linux process address space explain?

Tags: linux

In linux every process have address space and this address space will be over written by exec() system call when child process is created. What i want to know is what this address space consists of ? What kind of information will be in the address space ?

Comment: Something like this? http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-viewing-process-address-space-command/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The address space consists of a number of memory segments. Among them:

- The program's executable code and static data
- The heap
- The stack
- Shared libraries that were loaded when the program was launched
- Additional files that have been mapped into the address space with `mmap()`.
- Shared memory segments
- etc...

Some segments are read-only (like the program's executable code, aka `.text`), others are writable (like the heap). Some are backed by files on disk, some are purely memory-based.

In Linux, you can look at the contents of `/proc/<pid>/maps` for any process ID to see what segments are part of that processes' address space.

When you successfully call `exec()`, all of the segments in the current process' address space are unmapped, and the new executable gets a brand new set of basic mappings (stack, heap, program code, etc...) when it starts.

Comment: I often suggest to `cat /proc/self/maps` to see the address space of the process doing that `cat`; also, notice that some syscalls (notably `mmap` and `munmap`) are *changing* the address space.